MS SQLServer jdbc PreparedStatement bug
I want to insert rows into a table with 118 column.
I experience that it works perfectly with mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre8.jar but unfortunately with any later issue (I testes all from 9.2.1 to 12.8.1 ) gives back java.sql.BatchUpdateException, with a note that the column length at the 118. position is invalid. It happens only if the 118. column is VARCHAR or NVARCHAR. No error in the case of FLOAT or other numeric types. So if anybody has already faced with this, or know any solution, please let me know. Here is my PreparedStatement's command:
insert into tt
(CUSTOMER_ID,Value_date,_default,J_termek1,J_termek2,J_termek1_appl_pont,J_termek1_beh_pont,J_termek2_appl_pont,J_termek2_beh_pont,J_t
ermek1_appl_intercept,J_termek1_appl_beta,J_termek1_beh_intercept,J_termek1_beh_beta,J_t
ermek1_appl_weight,J_termek1_beh_weight,J_REL_def_STD,J_macro_correction,J_termek2_appl_intercept,J_termek2_appl_beta,J_termek2_beh_in
tercept,J_termek2_beh_beta,J_termek2_appl_weight,J_termek2_beh_weight,J_termek1_weight,J_termek2_weight,L_termek1,L_
termek2,L_termek1_appl_pont,L_termek1_beh_pont,L_termek2_appl_pont,L_termek2_beh_pont,L_termek1_appl_intercept,L_termek1_appl_beta,L_t
ermek1_beh_intercept,L_termek1_beh_beta,L_termek1_appl_weight,L_termek1_beh_weight,L_REL_def_STD,L_macro_correction,
L_termek2_appl_intercept,L_termek2_appl_beta,L_termek2_beh_intercept,L_termek2_beh_beta,L_termek2_appl_weight,L_termek2_beh_weight,L_t
ermek1_weight,L_termek2_weight,S_termek1,S_termek2,S_termek1_appl_pont,S_termek1_beh_pont,S_termek2_appl_pont,S_term
ek2_beh_pont,S_termek1_appl_intercept,S_termek1_appl_beta,S_termek1_beh_intercept,S_termek1_beh_beta,S_termek1_appl_weight,S_termek1_b
eh_weight,S_REL_def_STD,S_macro_correction,S_termek2_appl_intercept,S_termek2_appl_beta,S_termek2_beh_intercept,S_te
rmek2_beh_beta,S_termek2_appl_weight,S_termek2_beh_weight,S_termek1_weight,S_termek2_weight,O_termek1,O_termek2,O_termek1_appl_pont,O_
termek1_beh_pont,O_termek2_appl_pont,O_termek2_beh_pont,O_termek1_appl_intercept,O_termek1_appl_beta,O_termek1_beh_i
ntercept,O_termek1_beh_beta,O_termek1_appl_weight,O_termek1_beh_weight,O_REL_def_STD,O_macro_correction,O_termek2_appl_intercept,O_ter
mek2_appl_beta,O_termek2_beh_intercept,O_termek2_beh_beta,O_termek2_appl_weight,O_termek2_beh_weight,O_termek1_weigh
t,O_termek2_weight,H_termek1,H_termek2,H_termek1_appl_pont,H_termek1_beh_pont,H_termek2_appl_pont,H_termek2_beh_pont,H_termek1_appl_in
tercept,H_termek1_appl_beta,H_termek1_beh_intercept,H_termek1_beh_beta,H_termek1_appl_weight,H_termek1_beh_weight,H_
REL_def_STD,H_macro_correction,H_termek2_appl_intercept,H_termek2_appl_beta,H_termek2_beh_intercept,H_termek2_beh_beta,H_termek2_appl_
weight,H_termek2_beh_weight,H_termek1_weight,H_termek2_weight,H_atlag_pd,spare3,BEH_PD,behpd,txt1) VALUES
(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

I tried to use NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR without success. I also tried adding one more VARCHAR column to the insert (I created a new table before that with that additional column) and in this case the error message said that the error happens at 119. column (the new one). Stack trace:
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: A rendszer érvénytelen oszlophosszt kapott a BCP-ügyféltől a következő oszlopazonosítóhoz: 118.
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:2042)
   at SAS2SQL.writeToOutput(SAS2SQL.java:1098)
   at SAS2SQL.main(SAS2SQL.java:121)

The error message is in Hungarian. In English it is:

The system received an invalid column length from the BCP client for the following column ID: 118

The part of the code arranging the insert:
        String str = stdin.readLine();
        while (str != null) {
            counter++;
            //log(str);
            split(str);
            //log(arrayToText(elemek));
            int k;
            for (int j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
                tip=fieldtypes[j];
                textelem=elemek[j];
                k=j+1;
                if (textelem==null)pstmt.setString(k,null);
                else {
                    if (tip==Types.VARCHAR || tip==Types.NVARCHAR ) {
                    pstmt.setString(k, textelem);
                    
                    //if (insertedRows<15) log("TXT: "+textelem);
                    }
                if (tip==Types.INTEGER ||
                    tip==Types.BIGINT ||
                    tip==Types.SMALLINT ||
                    tip==Types.TINYINT 
                         ){
                         //log2("INT:"+Float.parseFloat());
                         if (textelem.trim().equals(".")) pstmt.setNull(k, java.sql.Types.FLOAT);
                         else pstmt.setFloat(k, Float.parseFloat(textelem));
                         }
                if (tip==Types.FLOAT ||
                    tip==Types.NUMERIC ||
                    tip==Types.DOUBLE ||
                    tip==Types.DECIMAL ) {
                         if (textelem.trim().equals(".")) pstmt.setNull(k, java.sql.Types.DOUBLE);
                         else pstmt.setDouble(k, Double.parseDouble(textelem));
                        }
                if (tip==Types.DATE) {
                        if (textelem.trim().equals(".")) pstmt.setNull(k, java.sql.Types.DATE);
                        else pstmt.setDate(k, java.sql.Date.valueOf(textelem));
                        //log2("DATE:"+SASResultSet.getDate(j).toString());
                     }
                if (tip==Types.TIMESTAMP) {
                        if (textelem.trim().equals(".")) pstmt.setNull(k, java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP);
                        else pstmt.setTimestamp(k,Timestamp.valueOf(textelem.trim()));
                     }
                if (tip==Types.TIME) {
                        if (textelem.trim().equals(".")) pstmt.setNull(k, java.sql.Types.TIME);
                        else pstmt.setTime(k,Time.valueOf(textelem.trim()));
                        //log2("TIME:"+SASResultSet.getTime(j).toString());
                     }
                    }
                 }
            str = stdin.readLine(); 
            insertedRows++;
            pstmt.addBatch();
            bulkcounter++;  
            if (bulkcounter==batchSize){
                pstmt.executeBatch();
                pstmt.clearBatch();
                bulkcounter=0;
                if (monitor)log(getTime()+" / "+insertedRows);
                }
             //pstmt.executeUpdate();
            }
        if (bulkcounter!=0) {
            pstmt.executeBatch();
            pstmt.clearBatch();
            if (monitor)log(getTime()+" / "+insertedRows);
            }
        //if (siker==0) log(""+counter+". sor beszúrása sikertelen");   
        sqlServerConnection.commit();
        //outputConnection.commit();
        stdin.close();
        pstmt.close();
        log("Number of inserted rows: "+insertedRows); 


This does not look like a normalized schema to me.   118 columns?   Too many.   Those subscripts suggest that it's an easy problem with a one-to-many arrangement.   More flexible, too.

Can you post the exact error and stacktrace and the code that does the jdbc stuff? If possible, a minimally recreatable example

That looks heavily denormalised. You have multiple different prefixes for the same columns (J_, L_, S_, etc) and then you also have things like J_termek1 and J_termek2. There should  be a termek column and Prefix (or better name to describe what J_ means) column, and then 1 row per different prefix and instance of said termek. If you do need to denote if it's termek 1 or 2 add an additional column for that. The table look like it should have about 20 columns at most, not 115.

you don't even mention what the value is you're trying to enter. But, seriously: 100+ columns in one table? Just forget about a DB and store it all in txt files

I would suggest your table's definition should look more like this: db<>fiddle

Pardon me, but it's not clear (to me) what the problem is. [Edit] your question and post the entire error message and stack trace. By the way, have you read [ask] ?

Can you check what is the data type of the column at the position?
If it is VARCHAR/NVARCHAR try to disable sendStringParametersAsUnicode and then execute your query. Else you would need to change your code to accept only numeric for this column

The issue could be that you're hitting the max row page size (8000) for your insert. A lot of non-varchar max columns can do that

Please do not torture me with critics about the database. I did not designed that, my task is to feed it, not to redesign. Actually the database is given, and I try to reproduce the error in the UAT environment too, that is why I was able to experience a little bit with columns, column types. The task is still the same, inserting data to the original table.

@Stultuske the value can be anything the ERROR appears. It appears at empty string, "AAAAAA", "123". Anything. I used only text with less than 10 character.

@siggemannen Good point! The problem is that it worked with older driver versions.

@Paul
the problem does not depend on that the column is VARCHAR or NVARCHAR. Its length is 10.

Still no stacktrace or a repro example, it's gonna be hard to help you :)

@ThomA The database is given. Not my design, I have to adapt. I reproduced the problem in UAT environment, that is why I could make minor changes in the table structure for experiencing.

@siggemannen The stacktrace is this: bold  java.sql.BatchUpdateException: A rendszer érvénytelen oszlophosszt kapott a BCP-ügyféltől a következő oszlopazonosítóhoz: 118.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:2042)
at SAS2SQL.writeToOutput(SAS2SQL.java:1098)
at SAS2SQL.main(SAS2SQL.java:121)

@siggemannen I see the Exception is in hungarian, but that is what I get. In english it means that wrong column length was received for column 118.

Add details to the question, nor in comments. Use edit.

https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/2444 perhaps? Try setUseBulkCopyForBatchInsert=false perhaps to keep the original functionality

@siggemannen Good point again. I believed it would solve the problem, but unfortunately not. I am facing the same error. Something fundamental changed between 8.4.0 and 9.1.x version of the driver, because that is the point where it starts to fail.

You should at least get different error, because it will use non-bcp mode

@siggemannen I will transform the program using execute with single inserts to check if the bulkcopy is the problem or not. My guess is that probably your original idea of the page size could be the explanation.

@siggemannen You were right. ( Unfortunately I left another line of setting that property you mentioned). So the problem is that the bulkcopy client has its narrower limitationthan the original engine. setUseBulkCopyForBatchInsert=false solved the problem. Thanks for the help!

I would be really interested to see how you call PreparedStatement, if you use setString or setObject or something else. Anyways, i'm pretty sure it's a sql server jdbc bug, they are usually good at fixing those, if one properly report it with reproducable example

@siggemannen I inserted the relevant part of my code into my question.

Please add an issue for the driver team here: https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues

@david Adding the issue on github is done.

So the problem is that the bulkcopy client has its narrower limitation than the original engine.
setUseBulkCopyForBatchInsert=false solved the problem.

The correct solution is that in the PreparedStatement instead of setFloat, setDouble, setString functions the setObject must be used to inject and the problem does not arise. By the way the setObject function makes type conversions, it can be feed by String and it converts it to Float, Double, Integer whatever is necessary.

well, I always used setString, setInt, ... it works if using the correct type for the corresponding column (but I never had that many columns)
